# Finding and substituting a list of words in a file using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to print the contents of a file to the terminal and in the process highlight any words that are found in a list without modifying the original file. Here's an example of the not-yet-working code:

```py
    def highlight_story(self):
        """Print a line from a file and highlight words in a list."""

        the_file = open(self.filename, 'r')
        file_contents = the_file.read()

        for word in highlight_terms:
            regex = re.compile(
                  r'\b'      # Word boundary.
                + word       # Each item in the list.
                + r's{0,1}', # One optional 's' at the end.
                flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)
            subst = '\033[1;41m' + r'\g<0>' + '\033[0m'
            result = re.sub(regex, subst, file_contents)

        print result
        the_file.close()

highlight_terms = [
    'dog',
    'hedgehog',
    'grue'
]
```

As it is, only the last item in the list, regardless of what it is or how long the list is, will be highlighted. I assume that each substitution is performed and then "forgotten" when the next iteration begins. It looks something like this:

> <kbd>Grues</kbd> have been known to eat both human and non-human animals. In poorly-lit areas dogs and hedgehogs are considered by any affluent <kbd>grue</kbd> to a be delicacies. Dogs can frighten awat a <kbd>grue</kbd>, however, by barking in a musical scale. A hedgehog, on the other hand, must simply resign itself to its fate of becoming a hotdog fit for a <kbd>grue</kbd> king.

But it should look like this:

> <kbd>Grues</kbd> have been known to eat both human and non-human animals. In poorly-lit areas <kbd>dogs</kbd> and <kbd>hedgehogs</kbd> are considered by any affluent <kbd>grue</kbd> to a be delicacies. <kbd>Dogs</kbd> can frighten away a <kbd>grue</kbd>, however, by barking in a musical scale. A <kbd>hedgehog</kbd>, on the other hand, must simply resign itself to its fate of becoming a hotdog fit for a <kbd>grue</kbd> king.

How can I stop the other substitutions from being lost?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify your regex to the following:

```
regex = re.compile(r'\b('+'|'.join(highlight_terms)+r')s?', flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)  # note the ? instead of {0, 1}. It has the same effect
```

Then, you won't need the `for` loop.

This code takes the list of words and then concatenates them together with a `|`. So if your list was something like:

```
a = ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse'];
```

The regex would be:

```
\b(cat|dog|mouse)s?
```

Answer (score 4):

The regex provided is correct, but the for loop is where you got wrong.

```
result = re.sub(regex, subst, file_contents)
```

This line substitutes the `regex`  with `subst` in the `file_content`.

in the second iteration, it again does the substitution in `file_content` where as you intented to do it on `result`

**How to correct**

result = file_contents

```
for word in highlight_terms:
    regex = re.compile(
          r'\b'      # Word boundary.
        + word       # Each item in the list.
        + r's?\b', # One optional 's' at the end.
        flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)
    print regex.pattern
    subst = '\033[1;41m' + r'\g<0>' + '\033[0m'
    result = re.sub(regex, subst, result) #change made here

 print result
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to reassign `file_contents` each time through the loop to the replaced string, reassigning `file_contents` does not change the content in the file:

```
def highlight_story(self):
        """Print a line from a file and highlight words in a list."""

        the_file = open(self.filename, 'r')
        file_contents = the_file.read()
        output = ""
        for word in highlight_terms:
            regex = re.compile(
                  r'\b'      # Word boundary.
                + word       # Each item in the list.
                + r's{0,1}', # One optional 's' at the end.
                flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)
            subst = '\033[1;41m' + r'\g<0>' + '\033[0m'
            file_contents  = re.sub(regex, subst, file_contents) # reassign to updatedvalue
        print file_contents
        the_file.close()
```

Also using with to open files is a better way to go and you can make a copy of the string outside the loop and update inside:

```
def highlight_story(self):
    """Print a line from a file and highlight words in a list."""
    with open(self.filename) as the_file:
        file_contents = the_file.read()
        output = file_contents # copy
        for word in highlight_terms:
            regex = re.compile(
                r'\b'  # Word boundary.
                + word  # Each item in the list.
                + r's{0,1}',  # One optional 's' at the end.
                flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)
            subst = '\033[1;41m' + r'\g<0>' + '\033[0m'
            output = re.sub(regex, subst, output) # update copy
        print output
    the_file.close()
```